# Live Audio Visual Display of Acoustic Data in JupyterLab

Tags: python, audio

### What I have:

- A kubernetes container, running Ubuntu and JupyterLab; JupyterLab is accessed remotely from a Windows laptop running a Chrome browser
- Audio files:  Wav format, 16 KHz mono
- Various technical derivatives of the audio files.  The most easily recognizable to a broad audience is likely the spectrogram, which is:  A 2d array of data, where time is displayed on the x-axis and various frequency data are displayed on the y-axis.  Each position on the horizontal axis represents an acoustic frame of data, typically high tens or low hundreds of samples.  ***These frames may overlap***.  This is true of all the 2d derivatives I want to investigate.
- (It should not matter, but for the curious, the other derivatives include things like MFCC representations, Mel Spectrograms, MGCEPs, various vocoder outputs, and a few experimental ones.)

### What I want:

- In general:  A tool set (likely but not necessarily something in the vein of a python library centered around widgets) that will, ***in JupyterLab***, allow me to display the audio or audio derivatives, play them, and provide a live visual indicator of what part of the audio is playing.
- Most important:  The play/display of the raw audio (shown in the link below)
- Second most important:  The play/display of an actual spectrogram
- Ideally:  The ability to substitute any spectrogram-like display for the spectrogram.
- Example is a typical Audacity display, [shown in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WYw3qoTdU4), but I know of no comparable tool in the intersection of python/widgets/jupyterLab.
- Note:  As the author and end-user of these alternate 2d forms of acoustic data, assume I have detailed (indeed, perfect) understanding of the frame overlaps, frame spacing, etc.

### What I currently use:

- IPython.display.audio, which plays live audio with a sort of a progress bar (see [this link](https://musicinformationretrieval.com/ipython_audio.html), about halfway down in section 8 for an example; in fact, see just above it in section 7 for an example of a spectrogram) but no real visual display of the data itself.
- A sad trombone, because that's just not enough.